# what is the most efficient way to generate warning/error logs from inside rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I want to generate some logs from inside the rails app/models files.

Given the multi-threaded environment like a web application, what is the best efficient way to do so?  If we tunnel all the logs to a file, there must be a way to synchronize this action, and does this cost a lot?

Comment: Have you tried using the normal `Rails.logger` and run into problems?

Comment: @Brandan Agreed, the Rails.logger should work fine, you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Brandan I am more concerned with the multi-thread efficiency aspect of `Rails.logger`